# assign form values to struct in Golang

Tags: json, forms, go

I am working on a API-Rest in Golang. I'm using Gorm so I have the structs that represent the database tables. In *Create* I receive a Form with the values, but right now am having a doubt of how can I assign inmediatly all the values to the structure, because I have a table with 5 hundred fields and I cannot make assignments one by one, I was doint in this way:

```
json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(&myobject)
```

But there I had to receive a Json, and the client side is sending me a Form. So, how can I assign that values in a clean and readable way?

Comment: The cleanest way is to probably forgo decoding the request body, and just put the values directly into a struct.

Comment: Answered, but, I have to ask... how in the world did you end up with a table with 500 columns?

Comment: Check out the [binding](https://github.com/mholt/binding) library, which is designed to solve this problem

Comment: @Adrian Hi Adrian, I didn't made that design. Indeed I was surprised when I saw it, but it responds to a standar stablished in the company on which I am working, is strange but it's ok

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in way of unmarshalling a multipart/form-data body into a struct. However, Go *does* automatically parse form data into a `map[string][]string` in `Request.Form`, which you could convert to a `map[string]string` with a simple loop. Then you could transfer that to a struct yourself using reflection, or you could use a library like [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) or [gorilla/schema](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema).