# Golang serialize form-urlencoded to object

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I've made a post request where I'm sending data as JSON and this code creates a new row in the DB.

```
json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)
DB.Create(&user)
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
```

But parsing the form data shows this error
[image]
I figured this is how I would read every individual value

```
for key, value := range r.PostForm {
        fmt.Printf("Key:%s, Value:%s\n", key, value)
}
```

My model looks like this

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:"firstname"`
    LastName  string `json:"lastname"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
}
```

How would I convert this to user and insert to DB?

Comment: `json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)` is the correct way to decode a JSON request body.   Did that fail?  If it did fail,  then what is the error returned from Decode?

Comment: It does, I don't want to accept a JSON request body, I'm sending a request on postman as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: `u.FirstName = r.FormValue("firstname")` and so on.

Comment: Need to parse a URL encoded form to user

Comment: Works thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052311/assign-form-values-to-struct-in-golang

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it (a bit overengineered, better to use `r.FormValue`), without having to type the fields again, such as `r.FormValue("firstname")`, etc if you already know the data, types etc.

```
func handleUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := User{}
    userType := reflect.TypeOf(user)
    for i := 0; i < userType.NumField(); i++ {
        // Get the JSON tag of the field, use it for the r.FormValue
        f := userType.Field(i).Tag.Get("json")
        if f != "" {
            reflect.ValueOf(&user).Elem().FieldByName(
                userType.Field(i).Name).SetString(r.FormValue(f))
        }
    }
    // DB.Create(&user) need a reference to DB here.
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
}
```

Note: This is just an example that will work for string fields, may panic otherwise because it's calling `SetString`. Additionally, a field may not exist and could panic when trying to access it in the `FieldByName(...`, but I think your question was geared to this direction of not having to type each field, so leaving it as an example.

The right way to do it, as Cerise Limón pointed out, would be

```
func handleUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := User{}
    user.FirstName = r.FormValue("firstname")
    user.LastName = r.FormValue("lastname")
    user.Email = r.FormValue("email")
    // DB.Create(&user) need a reference to DB here.
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
}
```

Note that you can also add a method for populating the user with the form if you do this in several places, for example

```
func (u *User) setFormData(r *http.Request) {
    u.FirstName = r.FormValue("firstname")
    u.LastName = r.FormValue("lastname")
    u.Email = r.FormValue("email")
}
```

And then use it like this

```
func handleUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    user := User{}
    user.setFormData(r)
    // DB.Create(&user)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
}
```